# How to prevent sbt from running in a non-sbt directory?

Tags: sbt

Disclaimer: I remember there to have been a prior issue about this. Cannot find it now.

If launching `sbt` command in a non-sbt-project directory, it starts decorating the directory right away (s.a. downloading files and creating `target/`). This is unwanted behavior, since all it takes is one too many `cd ..` and you're getting these ghost projects set up.

Is there a standard way to prevent this?

I did a small script (in `~/bin/sbt.sh`) and set it as an alias for `sbt` (below). However, I'd like to be able to give a general, easier way to feel safe with sbt.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f ./build.sbt ] || [ -f project/build.scala ] ; then
  /usr/local/bin/sbt $@
else
  echo "No 'build.sbt' or 'project/build.scala' found - may not be a sbt project?"
  exit 1  
fi
```

This is on OS X using HomeBrew's sbt 0.13.5.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. It's in fact the feature of sbt that considers any directory a project. I personally like it very much.

As to answer your question with another - why do you think a sbt project should have `build.sbt` or `project/build.scala`? What about other `*.sbt` files or `project/*.scala` files (not to mention `project/*.sbt` files and so on)?

Comment: Naturally, the condition could be enlarged. The script is simply for my own first aid. I enjoy the way git and hg use an 'init' param to initiate an empty repository. Likewise, sbt could have a flag (or interactive question) before it creates target etc. Maybe existence of target is actually the right condition? Anyways - seems there are two camps of opinions on this.

Comment: I'd recommend filling an enhancement in ths Issues on github for sbt. That should not be that hard. Have you tried sbt-extras? It could have something similar already.